# KeyDown event doesn't fire on ContextMenuStrip with enter key?

Tags: .net, vb.net

.NET : I have a Context menu strip that I want to handle using keyboard keys.

I have the following event handler:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuEnterKey(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As KeyEventArgs) Handles ContextMenu.KeyDown

    If E.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        'Do some staff
    End If

End Sub
```

The events fires correctly with other keys except EnterKey.

Does anyone know what's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To which control's `KeyDown` event are you binding your handler? In the Forms designer the ? `KeyDown` event isn't even shown for `ContextMenuStrip` (at least here in VS2012, and I'm working in C#...) I can bind to in in code, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

But there is a `PreviewKeyDown` event in `ContextMenuStrip` which gets called for every keystroke within the context menu, also for the Enter key. Maybe this can help you?

Comment: Great ! PreviewKeyDown works perfectly ! Thanks :) !