# How to detect everytime a key has been pressed on a context menu (winforms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, contextmenustrip

In a Winforms application, I use a `ContextMenuStrip` (shown when right clicking on notification icon).

I would like to detect if a key has been pressed when context menu item is open (eg : by registering to an event).

There is no `KeyDown` event on `ContextMenuStrip`, unlike most controls.
However, there is a `PreviewKeyDown` event.
I have registered to that event, however it does not work as expected.

Here is my context menu :

```
Item1
Item2
SubMenu > SubItem1
          SubItem2
```

If I press a key while `Item1` is higlighted (mouse is on it), event is triggered. However, if I press a key when `SubItem1` is highlighted, nothing happen.

Same behavior happen if no item is highlighted :
If only context menu is opened (no item highlighted), event is triggered.
If sub context menu is opened (no item highlighted), event is not triggered.

---

Here is some code sample as requested :

```
//MainForm.cs
void ContextMenuStrip1PreviewKeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK"); //not always called, as explained above
}

//MainForm.Designer.cs (generated automatically by form designer)
this.contextMenuStrip1.PreviewKeyDown +=
  new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(this.ContextMenuStrip1PreviewKeyDown);
```

Comment: `PreviewKeyDown` [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751326/keydown-event-doesnt-fire-on-contextmenustrip-with-enter-key) - can you show your code

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: What's the actual requirement/the reason that you want to detect key downs? It looks like an XY problem.

Comment: I would like to detect if shift key has been pressed to change the text of some specific menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key state when a context menu strip is open, As an option you can handle [`Application.Idle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.idle?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event and will check the key state using [`GetKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
public const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(GetKeyState((int)key) & KEY_PRESSED);
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
}

void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!contextMenuStrip1.Visible)
        return;
    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.ShiftKey))
        someMenuItem.Text = "Shift is Down";
    else
        someMenuItem.Text = "Shift is Up";
}

protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: I was tempted to do the something similar with `GetAsyncKeyState()` and a timer. However I know some antivirus software are unhappy with too many frequent call to that api (eg : can be used for a keylogger). Your solution is much better.